# How can I add the created text channel to a category?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want my text channel to be added to an already created category, my code currently looks like this:

```
@client.command()
async def create_factory(ctx, *, args):
        name = ''.join(args)
        guild = ctx.message.guild
        await ctx.send ('**Firmen**\n'
                        'Firma wird erstelt bitte warten...')
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        channel = await guild.create_text_channel(name=name)
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        await ctx.send (f'Firma {name} wurde erstellt')
```

what and where do I have to add so that the channel is added to the category

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a category created, you can simply retrieve it's `Category` object and pass it as parameter when you create your new channel, something like this:

```
category_name = 'Your Category Name'
category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name=category_name)
channel = await guild.create_text_channel(name=name, category=category)
```

References:

- [create_text_channel()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Guild.create_text_channel)
- [discord.utils.get()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get#discord.utils.get)